# Will a rods edge rotate if a small force acts for a small ammount of time in the one edge and the information have not reached the other edge yet?

Tags: visible-light, information

So assume we have a rod capable of rotating at its center of mass. Now we apply a force at its right edge for a very short time. Let's assume also that by the time we stop applying that force the information of a force acting has reached its center. Now, will that information continue at the left edge and tell it that a force was acted and move it accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

The information is actually a slight bending of the rod that travels in a wave from one end to the other.  Imagine the rod is made out of soft rubber and you give one end a whack and watch the slow motion replay.  At first only the end you hit will compress and bounce away, and the rod will start to bend, while the end you didn't hit will be stationary for a moment.  But the bent rubber rod has a spring force trying to straighten it back out again, and it's this force that gets the far end moving.

If the rod isn't made of soft rubber, it still bends like that, just that the motions are too small and fast to see.  A steel rod will bend a tiny amount when struck, and then very high spring forces will make it return to its normal shape almost instantly.

Comment: Analogies are a good approach to explain things. Nice answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.